Can Next.js cache routes with search params?
I have a route named "/search", and it is a client component that shows contents according to search params.
For instance, when the URL is '/search?q=one', it sends a request with the query parameter and displays results related to the keyword 'one'.
app/search/page.tsx
import WaterFall from "@/components/layout/WaterFall"

interface Props {
  searchParams: {
    q: string
  }
}
export default function Page({ searchParams }: Props) {
  const keyword = searchParams["q"]?.trim()

  return (
    <main>
      <WaterFall param={{ keyword }} />
    </main>
  )
}

Waterfall.tsx (This file is big, to save everyone's time, I only post the code related to data fetching and displaying.)
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client"
import { FETCH_CARDS } from "@/lib/apolloRequest"
import 
interface Props {
  param: Object
}
export default function Waterfall({ param }: Props) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([])
  const { loading: initialLoading, data: initialData } = useQuery(FETCH_CARDS, {
    variables: {
      ...param,
    },
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialLoading || !initialData) return

    setCards(initialData.cards)
  }, [initialLoading])

  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Card key={card._id} card={card} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

Here is how the problem occurred: When I visited '/search?q=one', results about 'one' were displayed. Then I visited '/search?q=two', and I could see results about 'two'. Up till now, everything was fine. However, when I clicked the browser's 'back' button to navigate back to '/search?q=one', the URL changed to '/search?q=one', but the search results did not change at all -- they were still about 'two'.
Does Next.js cache a route with search params? From what I observed, search params are ignored. Is there any way to let it cache '/search?q=one' and '/search?q=two' respectively?
